# SSIS Derived Column Conditional Time Modification

Tags: sql-server, mysql, sql-server-2012, ssis, syntax

I'm using SSIS to transfer data from a MySQL database to a SQL Server one. There's one point that I'm currently stuck on, however. MySQL TIME datatype supports values greater than or equal to 24:00:00, whereas SQL Server TIME caps at 23:59:59. One of the tables I'm transferring has a TIME column that, in MySQL, is 24:00:00. As logically in our business case this is a 'stop time' and thus equivalent to 00:00:00, I'm attempting to find a way to use SSIS to convert to that should that value come up.

Derived columns seem the way to go about doing this, but I don't seem to have a firm grasp on the syntax and very few resources are out there for TIME literals in SSIS conditional expressions. This is what I'm attempting to work with so far:

```
time == '24:00:00' ? time = '00:00:00' : time = time
```

Which of course returns only errors as I'm certain that part of that syntax is incorrect. I have (I believe) the logic, just spottily documented syntax is the issue.

Comment: So,is 24:00 actually 00:00 *the next day*?

Comment: The date is irrelevant here actually. We're only using TIME, no ticks, no date storage. Basically I need to get SSIS to recognize a 24:00 time value and convert that to 00:00 in a conditional. But yes for logical business needs the two are equivalent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So close. It'd be

```
time == "24:00:00" ? "00:00:00" : time
```

The Ternary Operator looks like `(condition) ? true : false` With the notable exception of the ForEach Enumerator, nowhere else in SSIS expressions are you able to use an assignment like time = "00:00:00". It'll basically be implied by whatever column or variables it's being assigned to.

If the data type of `time` column is actually detected as `DT_TIME` the above expression is likely to break because that would be outside the allowable domain for DT_TIME values but it'd actually break/fail/error at the source component level (OLE DB/ADO NET/ODBC source)

Comment: Such strange syntax. At any rate, so there's no way to convert a DT_TIME (As that is what this is being interpreted as) of 24:00:00 into something else at the SSIS level because, by my understanding, SSIS doesn't even recognize 24:00:00 as valid in the first place? I suppose I could change the data at the MySQL level before transferring if need be.

Comment: That or you bring it in as a string (DT_STR, 8, 1252) and then I'd create a new column, `SQLCompliantTime` in this Derived Column to handle the "fixed" values. That or a case statement on extract. I prefer to fix as many data problems in the source as possible to make my SSIS as dumb as possible

Comment: CASE on extract ended up being the least egregious way to handle this.